# How to String Format

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I've an array of strings below and wanted to format like the followings, what is the best way of doing that?  Thanks in advance.

```
line[0] = "This is line one two tree";
line[1] = "This is Abc Cde";
line[2] = "This is cjdj";
```

I want it to format to display like this

```
This is line one two tree
This is Abc Cde..........
This is cjdj.............
```

Comment: Please keep comments civil and constructive.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the `string.PadRight()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx), coupled with determining which of the array of strings is the widest:

```
var width = line.Max(l => l.Length);
foreach (var l in line)
    Console.WriteLine(l.PadRight(width, '.'));
```

Comment: That works and is concise. However, I would get the max length once, otherwise you are re-computing it for every loop.

Comment: Extract out the `Max` before your loop and use that., +1

Comment: Fair enough, I'll update it...

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, line.Select(l => l.PadRight(line[0].Length, '-').ToArray());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `string.PadRight` to pad each string, up to the specified length, with instances of a specified character.

Answer (score -1):

Use PadRight:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx
e.g.

```
int len = line[0].Length;
Console.WriteLine(line[0]);
Console.WriteLine(line[1].PadRight(len,"."));
Console.WriteLine(line[2].PadRight(len,"."));
```

Comment: Why was this voted down when it answers the question?